# Register implementation of DataBinderListener in Grails application

Tags: grails, data-binding, listeners

Does anybody know how to enable *myDataBindListener* (that implements DataBindListener) in grails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside resources.groovy define it as a bean. This will register it with the spring application context and receive events.

```
beans {
  myDataBindListener(com.whatever.MyDataBindListener)
}
```

Comment: but http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0.M1/guide/theWebLayer.html Any bean in the Spring application context which implements that interface will automatically be registered with the data binder

Comment: Yes, registered with the databinder, not registered as a spring bean to start with. To quote"With enableSpringEventAdapter set to true instances of BindEventListener which are in the Spring application context will automatically be registered **with the data binder**."